# Jquery addClass() , removeClass() functions does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
$('.push').each(function(){
  if($(':first-child',this).hasClass( "activex" )){
    $(this).off().off('click').on('click',function(){
      var a = $(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/rcart.php",
        data:{'pid': a},
        success: function(data){
          var a= parseInt($('.cart').text());
          if((data.indexOf("2")) >= 0){
            console.log(data);
            console.log('not removed'); 
          }else{
            a--;
            console.log('removed');
            $(this).children().removeClass('activex');
            $('.cart').text(a);
          }
        }
      });
      console.log(a); 
    });
  }else{
    $(this).on('click',function(){
      var a = $(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/cart.php",
        data:{'pid': a},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          var a= parseInt($('.cart').text());
          if((data.indexOf("2")) >= 0){
            console.log('done'); 
          }else{
            a++;
            $('.cart').text(a);
            $(this).children().addClass('activex');
          }
        }
      });
      console.log(a); 
    });
  }
});
```

I am trying to remove the class activex whenever the button with class push has been clicked but its not working and  there's no error in the code and it's not removing the class. If i remove the class manually in the chrome console with  class .push it works.

I am trying to remove the class activex whenever the button with class push has been clicked but its not working and  there's no error in the code and it's not removing the class. If i remove the class manually in the chrome console with  class .push it works.

Comment: `$(this).children().removeClass('activex');` need to be `$(this).removeClass('activex');` and same for other

Comment: please share the html

Comment: <button class="push" id="61"><i class="fa fa-heart  fa-2x activex"></i></button>         Heres html for the button and there are many buttons in the page

Comment: Please provide fiddle with html codes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated code, just i have removed children() from your code.
let me know if it helped or not.

```
$('.push').each(function(){


      if($(':first-child',this).hasClass( "activex" )){
          $(this).off().off('click').on('click',function(){
        var a = $(this).attr('id');
                $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/rcart.php",
    data:{'pid': a},
    success: function(data){


     var a= parseInt($('.cart').text());

     if((data.indexOf("2")) >= 0){
          console.log(data);
         console.log('not removed'); 
     }
     else {
     a--;
     console.log('removed');
     $(this).removeClass('activex');
     $('.cart').text(a);
     }
    }

    });

        console.log(a); 
    });

      }

      else {

    $(this).on('click',function(){
        var a = $(this).attr('id');
                $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/cart.php",
    data:{'pid': a},
    success: function(data){

    console.log(data);
     var a= parseInt($('.cart').text());

     if((data.indexOf("2")) >= 0){
         console.log('done'); 
     }
     else {
     a++;
     $('.cart').text(a);
     $(this).addClass('activex');
     }
    }

    });

        console.log(a); 
    });
      }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Sanjay , But the code does not work i  need to change class of the children of that element.

Comment: welcome @krishnasapkal, if still you will have any query about that then share your html, hope i will help you.

Comment: heres html code
<button class="push" id="61"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x activex"></i></button>